# Gentooo system mounts readonly, won't boot, services segfault

Tags: boot, gentoo, openrc

After upgrading to OpenRC 0.20 the system fails to boot properly:

```
mounted into runlelevel unknown (kernel 3.17.1)
```

The /  partition is mounted read-only

```
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (ro, realtime, data=ordered)
```

so I did the following:

```
# mount / -o remount,rw
```

.. whch worked, after that I did

```
# mount -a
```

which mounted my /dev/sda4 (/home)

But any service I try to start gets me a segfault, e.g.

```
# service root start
Segmentation fault
```

I am running openrc 0.20 which seems to have been installed yesterday in my latest emerge world.

Comment: What is dmesg showing ?

Comment: @Iddo please do not add "SOLVED" to the question title.  You can indicate the problem is solved by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.  You self-answered so you will have to wait 2 days to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would boot into single user mode (init=/bin/bash) and run revdep-rebuild, dispatch-conf and make sure your openrc configuration file is sane.

Answer (score 2):

So here's how I solved this.

Had to run /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd to regain my /dev/fd (even though the system is openrc, not systemd)

Downgraded to openrc-0.18.4 (was running 0.20 which I emerged yesterday)

```
emerge -uDav @world
```

reboot

Seems like openrc-0.20 disagrees with me :)